# on counting of special case of trees on a graph

Tags: graph-theory

Lets define *edge-cycle* in a graph $G$ as a path where the first and the last node are adjacent.
(in contrast with the definition of *cycle* where first and last node are the same).

An *edge-tree* $T$ is a tree with the additional property that doesn't have an edge-cycle.

In a graph we can compute the number of spanning trees by using the [Matrix-Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_theorem) theorem.

> Is there any similar theorem for the computation of the number of edge-trees of a graph?

Comment: What is the difference between "no edge-cycle" and "no cycle"?

Comment: Or does "adjacent" mean "adjacent in the ambient graph"?

Comment: If by ambient graph, you mean the graph G, my answer is yes.

Comment: By your definition, if $u$ and $v$ are joined by an edge in $G$, then the path $u,v$ is an edge cycle. So any spanning tree of a graph with at least two vertices has an edge-cycle. 

Maybe you want to change your definition of edge-cycle to require that the path contain at least three vertices?

Comment: Well, technically katsarola wanted to count edge-trees, not necessarily spanning edge trees, even though the Matrix-Tree theorem counts spanning trees.  If spanning edge-trees are wanted, then there is 1 if the graph is a tree, and none otherwise.  If it's edge-trees that are wanted, it looks like we just want to count induced subgraphs that are trees.  

Comment: @Tony Huynh: that is correct. Lets assume that we want to count the number of maximal edge-trees (edge-trees that no edge/vertex can be added without forming an edge-cycle) or edge-trees of size k.

Comment: Among other things this theorem you are looking for will give the number of subtrees of a tree. This suggests there is no closed form of the number of edge-trees for most graphs. Or are you looking for an algorithm?

Comment: @Gjergji Zaimi : I am looking for a theorem which will help me to efficiently enumerate edge-trees of a graph. So if there already exists such an algorithm, I would love to know.

Comment: So an edge-tree is what is more commonly called an induced tree, right?

Comment: The point of this comment is to explain why your definition is the same as "induced trees". Let S be a set of vertices of G. Let H by the subgraph induced by S http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_graph_theory#Subgraphs. I claim that there is an edge-tree with vertex set S if and only if H is a tree. Proof: Clearly, if H is a tree, it is an edge tree. Now, let T be a tree with vertex set S. Suppose that (u,v) is an edge of H not in T. Trees are connected, so there is a path through T from u to v. Adding the edge (u,v) to this path shows that T is not an edge-tree.

Comment: @David Speyer : Lets G be the cycle graph abcda and H the graph abcd. Then H is induced by G and is a tree but not an edge-tree. Forgive me if I miss something obvious, but did you mean "..S be a proper subset of vertices of G"?

Comment: No, a path with four vertices is *not* an induced subgraph of a cycle on four vertices.

Comment: Of course, you are right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll answer a question raised in the comments:

**Problem**: Count the number of induced trees of size $k$.

According to this [paper](http://www.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1986-08.pdf) by Erdös, Saks and Sos, it is NP-complete to decide given a graph $G$ and an integer $k$, if $G$ contains an induced tree of size $k$.  So, it's probably pretty damn hard to count them.  Apparently, it remains NP-complete even for bipartite graphs.

Actually, the argument is pretty simple so I'll include it here.  Given a graph $H$ and an integer $k$, it is well-known that the problem of deciding if $H$ has an independent set of size $k$ is NP-complete.  Suppose that $H$ has $n$ vertices.  Let $G$ be the graph obtained from $H$ by first adding a disjoint copy of $P_n$ (a path on $n$ vertices), and then connecting one end of $P_n$ to all the vertices in $H$.  Clearly, $H$ has an independent set of size $k$ if and only if $G$ contains an induced tree of size $n+k$.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading your definitions right, I believe the answer is that there are zero edge-trees of G if G has any cycle. And one if G is a tree itself (T=G)

Proof:
  If G has a cycle C, then for any spanning tree T of G there exist an edge E(u,v) of C that is not in T. Since T is a spanning tree, there is a path from u to v in T, and u and v are adjacent in G, thus the path from u to v is an edge-cycle, therefore there is always an edge-cycle in T. Therefore there are zero edge-trees of G.

Comment: I don't think the edge trees are required to be spanning trees.

Comment: I thought this too initially (but it's not right).  Take the 3-cycle on vertices {a,b,c}, add a vertex e and an edge between a and e.  Then eabc and eacb are both spanning trees whose *endpoints* are not adjacent.

Comment: But eabc is not a spanning edge-tree, since it contains abc which *is* an edge cycle.  